# Problem with size of table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I tried to create a table of [Row,Column]=[8,6], and wide titles in each row. The result that I had in Pdfviewer is shown in the following picture.

[image]

I would like to know how to make table fits the a4 page size in the normal way.

Here is my Texmaker code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
N° & DESIGNATIONS DES POSTES & U & Quantites &  PRIX UNITAIRE (HT) &  Montant \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Poste 1 : Pieux} \\ 
\hline 
1.1 & Réalisation des pieux Ø 1200mm verticaux en terrain non rocheux  & ML &  2,286.00   
 & 55000.00
 &  125,730,000.00   
 \\ 
\hline 
1.2 & Fourniture et mise en œuvre des tubes métalliques Ø 50/60 pour auscultation sonique  & ML &  6,858.00   
 & 2500.00
 &  17,145,000.00   
 \\ 
\hline 
1.3 & Essais d'auscultation sonique  & U &  126.00   
 & 16000.00
 &  2,016,000.00   
 \\ 
\hline 
1.4 & Recepage des pieux  & U &  126.00   
 & 3700.00
 &  466,200.00   
 \\ 
\hline 
1.5 & Essais statiques des pieux isolés sous compression axiale & U & 1.00 & 1520000.00
 &  1,520,000.00   
 \\ 
\hline 
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{TOTAL (Poste 1) } &  146,877,200.00   
 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

If you have any suggestions or a new environnement that can be Added in the code, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The table is simply too big to fit. To fix it, you'd either have to shrink the font, or wrap the long titles. Either can be done, but which do you want to do?

Comment: You should use `tabularx` and the `>{\centering}X`  specifier for the second column.

Answer (score 2):

With `tabularray`. Second column is of `X` type. For better cells filling I would use `\small` font size:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\small
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {Q[c] X[j] *{4}{Q[c,m]}},
                 colsep=3pt,
                 row{1} ={c,m}
                 }
N°  &   {Designations\\ des postes} 
        & U &   Quantites 
                &  {Prix\\ unitaire (HT)} 
                    &   Montant         \\
\SetCell[c=6]{c}{Poste 1 : Pieux} 
    &   &   &   &   &                   \\
1.1 & Réalisation des pieux Ø 1200mm verticaux en terrain non rocheux
        & ML
            &   2,286.00
                &   55000.00
                    &  125,730,000.00   \\
1.2 &   Fourniture et mise en œuvre des tubes métalliques Ø 50/60 pour auscultation sonique
        & ML
            &   6,858.00
                &   2500.00
                    &  17,145,000.00    \\
1.3 & Essais d'auscultation sonique
        & U &   126.00
                &   16000.00
                    &   2,016,000.00    \\
1.4 & Recepage des pieux
        & U &  126.00
                &   3700.00
                    &   466,200.00      \\
1.5 & Essais statiques des pieux isolés sous compression axiale
        & U &   1.00
                &   1520000.00
                    &   1,520,000.00    \\
\SetCell[c=5]{c}    TOTAL (Poste 1)
    &   &   &   &   &   146,877,200.00  \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addednum:**
Version where for numbers are used `S` columns defined in `siunitx` package (loaded as TblrLibrary):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,
         group-separator={,}}
\small
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {Q[c] X[j] Q[c] 
                            Q[c, si={table-format=4.2}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=7.2}]
                            Q[c, si={table-format=9.2}] },
                 colsep=3pt,
                 row{1} ={c,m}
                 }
N°  &   {Designations\\ des postes} 
        & U &   {{{Quantites}}}
                &  {{{Prix\\ unitaire (HT)}}} 
                    &   {{{Montant}}}         \\
\SetCell[c=6]{c}{Poste 1 : Pieux} 
    &   &   &   &   &                   \\
1.1 & Réalisation des pieux Ø 1200mm verticaux en terrain non rocheux
        & ML
            &   2 286.00
                &   55 000.00
                    &  125 730 000.00   \\
1.2 &   Fourniture et mise en œuvre des tubes métalliques Ø 50/60 pour auscultation sonique
        & ML
            &   6 858.00
                &   2 500.00
                    &  17 145 000.00    \\
1.3 & Essais d'auscultation sonique
        & U &   126.00
                &   16 000.00
                    &   2 016 000.00    \\
1.4 & Recepage des pieux
        & U &  126.00
                &   3 700.00
                    &   466 200.00      \\
1.5 & Essais statiques des pieux isolés sous compression axiale
        & U &   1.00
                &   1 520 000.00
                    &   1 520 000.00    \\
\SetCell[c=5]{c}    TOTAL (Poste 1)
    &   &   &   &   &   146 877 200.00  \\
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimum response that will make the table fit on the page.

Before getting into the subtleties of a new table design package and the excellent Zarko`s answer, it's best to try the simple methods to understand where the problem lies.

Looking at your figure, it is clear that the second column is too wide and it will be better to limit its width and have its content on multiple lines.

This can be achieved by defining a new column type `\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` (package `array`)
where `#1` is the width of the column and its content will be ragged on the right, like normal text.

After compiling, you will find that the fifth column is too wide due to the length of the column header.

So now we define `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` to limit its width and center the content of the column.

Finally (this is optional), you may want to expand the cells vertically for a more airy look using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<factor>}`

Until now, code of the tabular remained intact.

[image: a]

This is the complete code,

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{array}% added <<<<
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% added <<<<
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}% added <<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}% optional: expand the cells <<<<
    
    \begin{tabular}{|c|R{0.35\linewidth}|c|c|C{0.15\linewidth}|c|}% changed <<<<<<<
        \hline 
        N° & DESIGNATIONS DES POSTES & U & Quantites &  PRIX UNITAIRE (HT) &  Montant \\ 
        \hline 
        \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{Poste 1 : Pieux} \\ 
        \hline 
        1.1 & Réalisation des pieux Ø 1200mm verticaux en terrain non rocheux  & ML &  2,286.00   
        & 55000.00
        &  125,730,000.00   
        \\ 
        \hline 
        1.2 & Fourniture et mise en œuvre des tubes métalliques Ø 50/60 pour auscultation sonique  & ML &  6,858.00   
        & 2500.00
        &  17,145,000.00   
        \\ 
        \hline 
        1.3 & Essais d'auscultation sonique  & U &  126.00   
        & 16000.00
        &  2,016,000.00   
        \\ 
        \hline 
        1.4 & Recepage des pieux  & U &  126.00   
        & 3700.00
        &  466,200.00   
        \\ 
        \hline 
        1.5 & Essais statiques des pieux isolés sous compression axiale & U & 1.00 & 1520000.00
        &  1,520,000.00   
        \\ 
        \hline 
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{TOTAL (Poste 1) } &  146,877,200.00   
        \\ 
        \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
    
\end{document}
```